# completion of the direct sum of $p$-norms of a collection of Banach spaces(possibly uncoutable index)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I was wondering if there is anywhere that I can find good proof of the completion of the direct sum of Banach spaces with the $p$-norm. I know that the completion consists of the collection of functions $f \in \prod V_i$ that satisfy $$\sum ||\pi_i(f)||^p < \infty $$In Pedersen Analysis Now he has a proof, but I am not a big fan of it. I like Pedersen's text because it's very precise, and I am able to understand a lot of his proofs but this proof I felt has some missing things(or I just didn't completely understand it). I searched the web for this, but couldn't seem to find anything. I know that there are proofs of a specific type of this i.e. sequence spaces $l^p$ completeness, but I want the general one.

Comment: How do you define the sum with uncountable index?

Comment: @Akira For this specific question, the function in the direct sum of these Banach spaces with the $p$-norm would satisfy $f(i) = 0$ for all but finitely many. If the function was in the completion of this direct sum, then this function would satisfy $f(i) = 0$ for all but countably many. Essentially you can think about this as a partial sum sequence.